# Make an Android live wallpaper respond to a key event?

Tags: android, key, overriding, volume, wallpaper

What I'm trying to do is make my live wallpaper take action when the device's volume button is pressed.

In my activity I simply override `onKeyDown()` to achieve this.

In my livewallpaper, I can't see anything to override or register as a listener to be able to do this.

Anyone done anything like this, or know it's not possible?